# Change Java.g4 grammar file

Tags: java, antlr, grammar

I need to get parameters of method declaration of java file. 
I am using JavaBaseListener interface and those method :

```html
@Override
    public Object visitMethodDeclaration(JavaParser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) {
        TokenStream tokens = parser.getTokenStream();
        String type = "void";
        if(ctx.type() != null) {
            type = tokens.getText(ctx.type().getSourceInterval());
        }
        String args = tokens.getText(ctx.formalParameters());

        System.out.println("\t" + type + " " + ctx.Identifier() + args + ";");
        return super.visitMethodDeclaration(ctx);
    }
```

The problem is, that there are no white spaces between method name and method classname. 
Input : private void addLoan(Loan loan)

Output : void addLoan(Loanloan);

I tried to change java.g4 grammar file, and added whitespace there

formalParameter
:   variableModifier* type " " variableDeclaratorId
;

But now i have a lot of errors such as :

line 1:6 no viable alternative at input 'public '
line 1:12 extraneous input ' ' expecting Identifier
line 1:20 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'extends', 'implements', '{', '<'}
line 2:5 no viable alternative at input 'List '
...

What is the best solution for my problem and how can i handle it?
Thanks in forward

Comment: p.s. maybe someone has a good javabasevisitor usage example/tutorial, cause i didn't find anything

Comment: There is a visitor example in chapter 25-26 of [The ANTLR mega tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `java8` grammar found [in this repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4), the `WS` rule

```
WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
```

throws the white space away (`-> skip`).

Using the small grammar [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960604/wrong-rule-matched/46962547#46962547), you can see the difference between `-> skip` and `-> channel(HIDDEN)`.

With `WS : [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN) ;` the output is

```
Expression found : 3 + 4
```

With `WS : [ \t] -> skip ;` the output is

```
Expression found : 3+4
```

Using the command

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics input.txt
```

you can see that in the first case the `WS` tokens appear in the list of tokens, whereas they disappear in the second case.

[This other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872931/can-an-element-contain-attribute-as-parsed-by-parser-generated-by-antlr-if-so/46916429#46916429) clearly shows that `getText()` depends on it : `paydeltaco98`versus `pay delta co 98`.